# Problema al conectar con base de datos Mysql en android studio MainActivity

Tags: mysql, android-studio, kotlin, mysql-connect

Tengo una base de datos en amazon web services rds y me he podido conectar a esta base de datos atravez de jdbc connector implementando: mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.49 mediante el siguiente codigo:

```
fun connectToDatabase(): Connection? {
        val url = "jdbc:mysql://"Nombre de app"."Host"-2.rds.amazonaws.com/"Base de datos"?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
        val user = "usuario"
        val password = "contraseña"
    
        return try {
            DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
        } catch (e: SQLException) {
            null
        }
    }
```

Al ejecutar este codigo en un kotlin file.kt trabaja correctamente y puedo acceder a todos los datos que tengo en mi base de datos por medio de otra funcion para guardar todo en un Arraylist

pero al querer correr exactamente el mismo codigo en el MainActivity para mostrar los datos en una tabla en un layout, no permite la conexion, solamente me regresa null y no puedo conectarme, cabe aclarar que ya le di permisos de conexion internet a la app

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Aqui esta el MainActivity

````
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.sql.SQLException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val tvMostrarDatos = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvMostrarDatos)
        connectToDatabase()
        tvMostrarDatos.text = connectToDatabase().toString() // solamente para saber si se conecto la base de datos
    }

    fun connectToDatabase(): Connection? {
        val url = "jdbc:mysql://"nombredeapp".host-2.rds.amazonaws.com/"Basededatos"?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
        val user = "usuario"
        val password = "Contraseña"

        return try {
            DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
        } catch (e: SQLException) {
            null
        }
    }
}```
````

Al imprimir el error me da lo siguiente:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: Buenas, no estoy seguro pero me parece que ` DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)` es una llamada asincronica. Puedes poner el codigo del getConnection? El AS no muestra ningun warning o algo asi?

Comment: Cual es el mensaje deplegado en el LogCat, debes usar el LogCat de otra forma las razones de este problema pueden ser diversas. En lugar de capturar el error, imprimelo:  catch (e: SQLException) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getCause())
        }

Comment: ¿Por qué intentas conectar a una base de datos remota usando JDBC desde Android? Si esa aplicación la van a usar varios miles de clientes puede que termine siendo inviable. Y no digamos nada de los problemas de seguridad, al exponer directamente la Base de Datos... Deberías considerar programar un servicio web o una API en el servidor remoto y acceder a ella desde Android usando Retrofit u otro. [Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15853566/5587982) y algunas otras en esa misma pregunta, podrían ser esclarecedoras sobre por qué deberías evitar lo que intentas hacer aquí.

Comment: Al imprimir el error me da lo siguiente:                                                                                                     android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @Mshdevs revisa mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

**El problema es que estás tratando de realizar una operación para conectarte en una base de datos en el hilo principal**, por esta razón obtienes el error [**NetworkOnMainThreadException**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException), te sugiero en este caso usar un [Thread()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/lang/Thread) y **[runOnUiThread](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1d3joa_rlcb5wnnxgoE0rZB9dw07yTXl62G407AMLOlI/edit?resourcekey=0-BVwg-bp-VXfSGihbaHTv9w#heading=h.gogsi66llh5u)** ,

````
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val tvMostrarDatos = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tvMostrarDatos)

        Thread({
            //* llama proceso
            connectToDatabase()
            runOnUiThread({
                //* actualiza la UI
               tvMostrarDatos.text = connectToDatabase().toString() // solamente para saber si se conecto la base de datos
            })
        }).start()

    }

    fun connectToDatabase(): Connection? {
        val url = "jdbc:mysql://"nombredeapp".host-2.rds.amazonaws.com/"Basededatos"?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
        val user = "usuario"
        val password = "Contraseña"

        return try {
            DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password)
        } catch (e: SQLException) {
            null
        }
    }
}```
````

De esta forma evitarás el error [**NetworkOnMainThreadException**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException)

---

**Te sugiero evitar desactivar la política para no permitir operaciones en el hilo principal**.

```
val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)
```

ya que [StrictMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/StrictMode) es una herramienta para desarrolladores que detecta cosas que podrías estar haciendo por accidente y te las avisa para que puedas solucionarlas.

Answer (score -1):

Muchas gracias a los que contestaron, el error era porque no se pueden ejecutar funciones de network en el main thread, se tiene que hacer desde una funcion async aunque lo solucione de otra forma que al parecer no es la mas conveniente pero solamente se le tiene que agregar el siguiente codigo al main thead

````
``` val policy = ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build()
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy)```
````

aunque tomare en cuenta las recomendaciones que me dieron en los comentarios soy nuevo en estoy de programacion en android aunque gracias a sus comentarios pude solucionar el problema muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola amigo, esto no es una solución, en realidad, está deshabilitando una política para poder permitir realizar operaciones en el hilo principal, va a "funcionar" pero en realidad es incorrecto. Voy a agregar una respuesta.